# is there a way to prespecify to overwrite files with same name?

Tags: windows-7, networking, file-transfer, overwrite

Connections to network drives are ridiculously slow (e.g. 15kb/sec on really good days) and when I'm copying files I leave my desk. My problem is when there is a file with the same name to be overwritten, is there a way to specify in advanced to overwrite files? I know it has the option "do same for next x conflicts" but that doesn't popup until (in some cases) a long time after the files start copying. See my dilemma?

Example: copying 500 files, estimated time 2 hours, I leave, after 10 minutes message comes up about file with same name and asks if it should overwrite (in this time copying stalls), I come back 30 minutes latter to find only the files in the 10 minutes copied.

Out of curiosity how could the network speed be so bad? I asked the boss and he said because it gets routed around a lot and is just bad :(

Comment: Are you open to using the command line? I do not believe there's a way to preempt that prompt using the standard GUI copy/paste.

Comment: yes open to using command line

Comment: You can use the /y argument with either copy or xcopy, if you feel comfortable using either of those from the command line. http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/copy.mspx?mfr=true  Regarding your network speeds, I think 'the boss' might be a lousy resource. There aren't many good excuses for 15kbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the /y argument with either copy or xcopy, if you feel comfortable using either of those from the command line. ([microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/…](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/copy.mspx?mfr=true)) Regarding your network speeds, I think 'the boss' might be a lousy resource. There aren't many good excuses for 15kbs.